# Java - C-Like Fork?

Tags: java, c, fork

Is it possible to do  a "C like" fork in java, using an new independent jvm process ?

How?

Comment: Maybe you could go into greater detail about what you're trying to accomplish? As mentioned, you can exec() another process, which could be another instance of the JVM, but that doesn't give you the same state-sharing as fork() does in C. On the other hand, you can run threads, but there you get more sharing than you would with fork().

Comment: I simply want to avoid the sharing that thread implies. Thks for your concern :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Funnily, I am just working on this: a Java process running other Java processes. I used the article [From Runtime.exec() to ProcessBuilder](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/88888889-java-util/426-from-runtimeexec-to-processbuilder.html) as a solid base, and [When Runtime.exec() won't](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2) as a good advice how to gobble the output streams.

PS.: For those wondering, I had to do that (instead of spawning new threads) because yet another Java process is checking the presence of these processes which are, normally, ran separately with shell commands.

Comment: Those just refer to `Runtime.exec()`, which is WAY different from being able to explicitly control the child after a `fork()`.

Comment: Can you please update the answer and fix the link for ProcessBuilder?

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: This is an old answer, but if you still want to get the information, use the Wayback Machine to reach these old articles. Or search for newer ones?

Answer (score 15):

This answer is probably a little late but:

http://akuma.kohsuke.org/

seems to be exactly what your looking for

Comment: it seems that it doesn't truly fork but exec's new child processes in a way that gives some benefits like fork.

Comment: Note that it works only on POSIX-like system (so roughly everything but Windows)

Comment: You can read the source code of Akuma, and use posix API using JNA like akuma does.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

The [Application Isolation API (JSR 121)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=121) introduces `Isolate` which addresses this use case.

Comment: As far as I can see, the isolation API is not supported under the current (1.8) JDK. There is an experimental MVM (Multitasking Virtual Machine) project that does, but it did not find its way in the mainline. Moreover it seems to me that the the isolation API does not allow to do a fork, where the state of the forking process is cloned in to the child: As far as I could understand the isolate starts with a main method, and (of course) different isolates do not share state.