# Create Parent Thread in java

Tags: java

Often I create Child threads within the main() as

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(){}});
```

Likewise, is it also possible to create parent threads ?

Comment: What do you mean by "to create parent thread"? How could a running Thread spawn it's own creator? Or a child give birth to it's own father? I'm sure you meant something else.

Comment: In general, while the creating thread is often referred to as the "parent" and the created thread as the "child", there isn't usually a semantic relationship between the two. What functionality were you hoping to achieve?

Comment: like creating a independent thread uncreated to the main()

Comment: @Akash That just begs the question, though. For what purpose would you like such a thread? How would it be different from a normal thread?

Comment: ...You _cannot_ start a thread that isn't a descendant of the main thread.  Is that clear enough?

Comment: If you're trying to fork the parent process, this might be of use:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/287633/487075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runtime.exec()`?

see: [How to create a process in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006035/how-to-create-a-process-in-java)

I think we're really not sure what you mean by "parent thread" though...

From coderanch.com: http://www.coderanch.com/t/475322/threads/java/Parent-thread-id

> Except for the thread which is created by the JVM to start the
>   application, every thread is created by some other thread. You have
>   decided to call this the "parent thread"; that isn't a concept of the
>   Java language, though.

Answer (score 0):

**main() is the parent thread......**

Try this....

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println(Thead.currentThead().getName());


    }
```

Comment: @Akash thats impossible, unless you mean to spawn another process.