# Start a new OS process from Java

Tags: java, class, process, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - C-Like Fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287633/java-c-like-fork)

I have a static void main with this:

```
ScreenStarter.main(clients.get(i).getSocket(), clientips.get(i));
```

In ScreenStarter, I have another static void main Where I call following:

```
public static void main(Socket sock, String ip) throws IOException{
    new ClientConn(sock, ip).start();
}
```

Is it possible to start ScreenStarter as a seperate process?

Comment: Separate thread or actual separate OS process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need to add a method named

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

which can call your current ScreenStarter.main(). Then use one of the `exec()` methods from [java.lang.Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). Alternatively, you can use [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to spawn the second process. See [this article](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html) for a tutorial describing the differences between the two.