# Running exe from java code

Tags: java, swing

I've been working on in a swing application. I've a JFrame having some buttons and fields.

On some button click event,I'm opening an exe from my current directory. Everything works fine.

```
try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("user.dir") +
      "\\Upgrade\\Upgrade.exe");
      } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStacktrace();
        }
   this.dispose(); // disposing my current java file.
```

But what i need is to **exit** the java code after opening the exe file.

Anyone help to deal this.?

Comment: You can't. If the parent process closes, so will the child process.

Comment: Can you not just do System.exit(0);

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287633/java-c-like-fork

Comment: @david99world no still the instance is running..

Comment: Try something like `cmd.exe /c start upgrade.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try making it a process, then waiting for that process to finish before exiting, like so:

```
class SO {
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
    proc.waitFor(); //Wait for it to finish
    System.exit(0);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: @SanCJ  Glad it works, when you can the chance may I please have a green tick to show the questions as having an accepted answer =D

Answer (score 0):

Executing an application from java using Runtime.exec() is a source of well known problems. Like waiting for a Process to finish, but not consuming the data from the stream buffers is a sure way for you application to hang.

I would suggest you use a library like [Apache Common Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) to handle this.

I worked on a project a while back where we used Runtime.exec() to launch a process that would eventually extract files over existing files. All worked well except on one machine used for staging - it would just hang. It turned out on that staging machine, someone had set the date/time back so it looked liked the new files being extracted where older than the existing one, causing the external process to generate a warning message for each, overflowing the error buffer - which our application was not consuming!